# Any particular reason to use anchor tags for links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-analytics

I am working on a website for which I'd like to track user interactions. The nav bar at the top of the page has several links, for each of which I want to record clicks.

Each of these links is implemented as a `<span>`. I wrote some JS to run on page load to set up event listeners to monitor clicks on these elements. When an element in the nav bar is clicked, a function sends the event to GA, and then redirects the user to the appropriate page.

The alternative to what I'm doing would be to implement these elements as `<a>` tags and give them `onclick` attributes.

My question is: **is there any particular reason that I should be using `<a>` tags for these elements instead of `<span>`s?** I'm wondering because the `<a>` tag exists for the very purpose of redirecting users to different pages, which is what I'm doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Backwards Compatibility: Anchor tags work even with javascript disabled. Also, some browsers have a "reader" mode, and in those cases anchor tags may work better.
- Syntactic meaning: As you mentioned, Anchor tags are defined as link tags. That's their purpose. So if you see an anchor tag, you know what it should be doing.
- Accessibility: Screen readers and other devices know that anchor tags are link tags, and can treat them in a way that makes them easier to use and "display" with accessibility devices.
- Default behavior: browsers add special behavior to anchor tags, such as being able to tab through them, and recording if they were visited or not.

All that being said, you should use a tag like "button" if the intent is to handle some sort of action, and not to actually link to something. Now if you can't provide an `href` attribute that works if you type it in the browser, then it probably isn't a link.

Answer (score 1):

From SEO perspective, for example, it would be better to use `a` with a correct `href` that robot will able to recognize and follow. Even you'll handle a click with js and modify it - indexing robots will be happier with `a`.